# Discontinuity of Spin-Wave Stiffness in the 2D XY Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics

In the following paper [1], the main result (Theorem 3) shows that if the probability that the inner $i$ and outer boundary $o$ of a scaled annulus $A_{L_0}$ is connected (the event is denote by $T_{i,o}$) is sufficiently small for some finite scaling $L_0$, then as the scaling $L\to\infty$, the probability of connectivity $\to 0$. However, I don't quite understand its proof.

**Exposition**.
To be concrete, let $A$ denote a finite volume annulus in $\mathbb{R}^d$, say $A=\{1<|x|\le 2 \}$, and $A_L$ denote the lattice approximation to $A$ at scale $L$, i.e., $A_L = LA\cap \mathbb{Z}^d$ where $LA$ is scaling each point in $A$ by $L$. Let $\mathbb{M}_{A_L}$ denote the cluster probability (defined from the XY model with some boundary conditions on the inner and outer boundary $i,o$ of $A_L$) on the graph $A_L$. The theorem then claims that if there exists $L_0$ where $\mathbb{M}_{A_{L_0}}[T_{i,o}] < \epsilon_0$ (where $\epsilon_0$ is sufficiently small and to be determined), then
$$
\mathbb{M}_{A_{L}}[T_{i,o}] \to 0, \quad L\to\infty
$$

The proof starts by considering $A_{NL_0}$ where $N\gg 1$ and then dividing $A_{NL_0}$ into grids of scale $L_0$ (which I understand as considering $A_{NL_0} \cap L_0\mathbb{Z}^d$) so as to have the appearance of $A_N$ on the large scale lattice. It continues to state that "if $\mathscr{P}: i\to o$ is a path in $A_{NL_0}$, then each 'site' on the large scale lattice that is visited by $\mathscr{P}$ has achieved an event like $T_{i,o}(L_0)$". I don't quite understand what this means. One can "project" the path $\mathscr{P}$ onto the $L_0$-scale lattice via the closest $L_0$-site, but **I'm not sure what it means by "achieving an event like $T_{i,o}(L_0)$".**

It seems that I'm misunderstanding something, and cannot continue with the rest of the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

[1] Chayes, L. Discontinuity of the Spin-Wave Stiffness in the Two-Dimensional XY Model. Comm Math Phys 197, 623–640 (1998). https://doi.org/10.1007/s002200050466